# Corporate PKI Deploy (Digital Signature)

Tags: security, ssl, digital-signature

I'm looking for information regarding digital signatures for document signing (PDF, office, etc)

- What companies offer this service?
- Is it possible to steal a private-key and forge someones signatures? I believe it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check with different CAs, eg. [GlobalSign](http://www.globalsign.com/authentication-secure-email/enterprise-pki/), [Comodo](http://enterprise.comodo.com/security-solutions/digital-certificates/certificate-manager/index.php). The exact CA offering to use depends on your particular plans - do you want to purchase certificates one by one or you want to purchase a CA Certificate for your company and issue end-user certificates yourself.
2. Yes, it's possible unless you protect it properly. The best approach is to use USB cryptotoken (aladdin eToken, Rainbow, Athena - three names that come to mind, all searchable in Google). Once the private key is added, USB cryptotoken doesn't let it out, so one can't use the key unless s/he steals the device itself AND learns the PIN (passcode that protects the keys in the device).

Comment: Hello Eugene, thanks for the reply. I think the first option to get an CA would be the best. The company has 400-500 workers, so I think its better for an admin to issue end-user certificates.